# Give counterexample for $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)), \exists x(P(x)) \vdash \forall xQ(x)$

Tags: predicate-logic

I know this should be quite easy but I can't figure out how I have to write down a model as a counterexample for this:

$\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)), \exists x(P(x)) \vdash \forall xQ(x)$

Let's say

$ P = \{ \text{students who attended exam E.123} \}$

and

$ Q = \{ \text{students who passed exam E.123} \}$

How do I define my universe of values and how do I give the definitions of the functions and predicates? How to show a model $\mathcal{M}$ as counterexample?

---

Is it sufficient to define $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{M} = \{ a, b\}$ and say

$
\begin{align}
P_\mathcal{M}(a) &= T \\
P_\mathcal{M}(b) &= T \\
Q_\mathcal{M}(a) &= F \\
Q_\mathcal{M}(b) &= F
\end{align}
$

?

Comment: NO; you have to set : $P_M(a)=T, P_M(b)=F, Q_M(a)=T, Q_M(b)=F$. In this way both $∀x(P(x)→Q(x)), ∃x(P(x))$ are satisfied...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $\forall x ((x > 0) \rightarrow (x > 0))$ --- is the *generalization* of a tautology; thus, it is *valid*

2) $\exists x (x > 0)$ --- it is true in $\mathbb N$

3) $\forall x(x > 0)$ --- it is *false* in $\mathbb N$, because **not** $0 > 0$.

---

Of course, we can "shrinck" it to a model $\mathcal M$ with $|\mathcal M |= \{ 0,1 \}$.

Comment: I got it now! Thank you.